# Determining which file triggered an error, in Octave

Tags: octave

Here is an example of a recent error I got:

```
error: mx_el_eq: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x51, op2 is 1x53)
error: called from
    load at line 87 column 13
    collect at line 23 column 10
    run at line 78 column 7
    collector at line 47 column 1
    run at line 93 column 5
```

My problem is that I have many (static) functions called 'load()', belonging to different classes, and they are of course all in different files. I could just go through them all and check line 87, but this occurs often enough that I wish Octave could tell me in which file, or which class, the error was triggered.

How can I set up Octave (7.1.0) to share this info?

Comment: Interesting, such poor error messaging. That would definitely be a bug.

Comment: One thing you could do is `dbstop if error`, which will launch the debugger at the point the error is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for your input (and sympathy) @cris-luengo. I can't stop when the error occurs because I'm executing the code in the terminal, through an ssh connection, on a compute cluster. I don't think it's really a bug, it's just that Octave sucks.. sadly.

Comment: It’s a bug as in undesired behavior that should be corrected. The error message should refer to the complete function name (for class methods this is `class/function`). This is how MATLAB does it. MATLAB also makes the function names and line numbers into links.

Comment: There is an open Octave bug report on this. see https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?60264

Comment: The bug has been open since March 2021, with severity 'Normal'.  Anyway, thanks a lot @nick-j

Comment: That bug list goes back a decade. It's a big program with a target that moves every 6 months. If its not breaking functionality it gets fixed when someone has the gumption to put the time in.